# How to match version of a software using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have extracted a string from a device within which I have to find and match its version using regex. The string contains the version number of a software as well as other text.
Something of a form `1.2.3.x.z-2`

Basically it contains a mixture of numbers alphabets colons hyphens etc.
What do I match for in regex.

I tried the index of first and last number in the string and print all the data in between the 2 index. 
But this are not the only numbers present in the string. example, It may have something like date.

Even if I filter the other numbers later, What can I match for something that follows this kind of pattern ?

Comment: What is the exact form of the version? Where can it have numbers and letters, and what are the separators?

Comment: it is in the number.number.number-alphabet and number.number

Comment: The example in your question doesn't seem to follow that pattern?

Comment: @Marein haha yea my answer went off his example... shoot

Comment: @john It would also help if you could specify how many digits the numbers are and whether your letters are uppercase or lowercase :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the RegEx `\d\.\d\.\d-[a-z]\d\.\d`

The `\d` will match digits, the `\.` will match periods, the `-` will match the hyphen, and the `[a-z]` will match lowercase letters.

Comment: I wasn't sure if he wanted longer numbers so I did \d* in mine + 1 tho

Answer (score 1):

Using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and your test version supplied `1.2.3.x.z-2`
I came up with

`\d*[.]\d*[.]\d*[.][a-z]*[.][a-z]*[-]\d*`

for a Python regex

`\d` will match a single digit, `\d*` will match any number
`[.]` gets the dots between numbers, same with `[-]` except for dashes

Try regex101 because you can put all your version numbers in the test string section and it will tell you if the regex you try matches them all.

There is a quick reference on the lower right that tells you other regex methods and how they work

**Edit:** if your version is in the form `number.number.number-alphabet and number.number` the regex would be `\d*[.]\d*[.]\d*[-][a-z]* \d*[.]\d*` assumeing you mean a space when you say and...

Comment: Definitely more flexible than my answer :) but why are you using `[.]` instead of `\.` or `[-]` instead of `-`?

Comment: @victor I find it easier to read single characters in brackets, at least with regex. Especially if it is a regex that might change some day. Just my personal preference

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
(?:(?:\d+|[a-z])[.-]){2,}(?:\d+|[a-z])
```

This matches any sequence consisting of groups of digits or single lower case characters, joined by either `-` or `.`. There must be at least 3 (2+1) such groups for the sequence to be matched. For example all of the following are matched:

```
1.2.3
1.2.3-a
12.5.5
1.2.3.x.z-2
```

But these are not:

```
1.2 (too short)
1.ab.3 (multiple consecutive characters)
1..3.4 (missing group)
1.2.C (upper case character)
```

A large part of the expression is repeated (`(?:\d+|[a-z])`), I'm not sure if there is a way to prevent this.